# Missing template argument before start

Tags: c++, templates, vector, linked-list

I am trying to compare the time taken to populate a vector against a linked list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   list<int> mylist;
   vector<int> myvector;
   srand(time(NULL));
   int num;

   clock_t list_start;
   clock_t list_end;

   list start = clock();

   for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000 ; i++ ) // 1 billion times
   {    
        num = rand() % 1000000000 ;        
        mylist.push_back(num);
   }

   list end = clock();

   cout << difftime(list_start,list_end);       
   cout <<" List is done ";

   clock_t vector_start;      
   clock_t vector_end;

   for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000 ; i++ ) // 1 billion times
   {    
        num = rand() % 1000000000 ;       
        myvector.push_back(num);
   }

   cout << difftime(vector_start,vector_end);       
   cout << " Vector is done " ;

}
```

I get the following error

> missing template argument before start;
>   expected ; before start

How do i correct these errors?

Comment: In your mind, what does `list start = clock();` mean?

Comment: Based on the declaration and usage later it seems you are missing some underscores.

Comment: "missing template arguement before start;" well, add one?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
list start = clock();
```

to

```
list<int> start = clock();
```

It will fix an error.
But probably you was going to write

```
list_start = clock();
```

Thanks to @Retired Ninja

Comment: It's more likely he meant to use `list_start` but didn't.  What you've suggested doesn't compile for me.

Answer (score 1):

`list start = clock();` does clock return a list object. That should be `list_end = clock();`